# Firestore data structure for a hotel reservation system

Tags: firebase, nosql, google-cloud-firestore

I want to build a hotel reservation system that also will push availability to the channel manager. I want to use Firestore to store my data. I read a few articles but still pretty new to this.

I am planning to set up my database using a structure like this:

> collection: "reservations"
>
> fields: reservation_id, status, name, email, check-in date, check-out date, room_id, etc
>
> collection: "rooms"
>
> fields: room_id, room_type, room_number,etc
>
> collection: "availability"
>
> fields: room_id, date, isAvailable
> examples: {room_id: 1, date: "2018-10-05", isAvailable: true}, {room_id: 1, date: "2018-10-06", isAvailable: true}

These are some situations I will need:

> Situation: A new booking is created
>
> I will create a new "reservation" doc and I will also update the "availability" docs for these dates.
>
> Situation: A multi-calendar view of all rooms
>
> I will get all docs for the dates and rooms and display in a grid

My questions are:

(1) Is this the best structure to set up for Firestore?

(2) Do I need to set "availability" as a subcollection of "rooms"?

The only thing is I need to get all rooms' availability quite often so that will cause lots of reading operations.

(3) Do I store Date as a timestamp object or a string? There's no hour/minute time involved so it looks a bit too much for me and I like "2018-10-05" it looks neat.

(4) How do I write the query to update availability when a new booking is created? How to get the date range I want?

Thank you for reading my questions :)

Answer (score 0):

> I recommend you to add `dateCreated` to reservations.

and for rooms you should also add **floor(1st/2nd)** and where is hotel level(I mean **5/4 stars**)

and you also need a hotel Collections for it's id,Name ,location,stars, isRestaurant Available, Parking Available etc..